# rtruncnorm function in R generates same observations

Tags: r, statistics, epoch, normal-distribution

I am trying to use truncated normal distribution function in R to generate numbers between upper and lower bounds. This is the statement I am using:

```
rtruncnorm(4,1494396000,1494397800, 6360,2640)
```

4 - Number of observations i need, 
1494396000 - Epoch time (actual time: 2017-05-10 02:00:00), 
1494397800 - Epoch time (actual time: 2017-05-10 02:30:00), 
6360 - mean 106 mins (106*60 = 6360 seconds),
2640 - SD  44 mins (44*60 = 2640 seconds)

This should ideally give me 4 observations of epoch times between 02:00:00 and 02:30:00 on May 10
But the output I am getting is: 1494396000 1494396000 1494396000 1494396000
which is 2017-05-10 02:00:00

I can't understand why rtruncnorm is giving me 4 exactly same observations. I tried using rtnorm function from msm package and the result is the same.

A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower truncation limit of 1,494,396,000 is 566,057 standard deviations above the mean of 6,360. It looks like when you specify a mean that results in all the simulated values being below the lower truncation limit, the function just returns the lower truncation limit for every value. I think you must have meant to specify a mean somewhere between your truncation limits.

```
library(truncnorm)

rr = c(1494396000, 1494397800)

hist(rtruncnorm(10000, 1494396000, 1494397800, 1494396000, 500), 
     breaks=seq(rr[1],rr[2], length=40), xlim=rr, main="Mean=1494396000", xlab="")

hist(rtruncnorm(10000, 1494396000, 1494397800, 6360, 500), 
     breaks=seq(rr[1],rr[2], length=40), xlim=rr, main="Mean=6360", xlab="")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @eipi10. I figured out the issue. The way epoch time is calculated in R (number of seconds from Jan 1, 1970), 2017-05-10 02:00:00 results in a very large number which is 1494396000.  While the mean and SD provided by the client is simply in minutes and has no date component attached to it and this results in such a huge difference between the range and mean & SD. Need to figure out a way to overcome this issue.

Comment: I would suggest that based on what you've just shared that a normal distribution probably does not model your problem very well. Poisson and exponential distributions are two (off the top of my head) that are more typically used in situations involving time

Answer (score 1):

(Eipi10 beat me to the punch, and this answer is meant to be a complement to theirs which explains *why* `R` behaves the way it does)

What you're essentially attempting to do is to pull values from the extreme end of a tail of a distribution with a standard deviation that's also very large relative to your limits. I have made a horrible quick picture in MSPaint to help demonstrate.

[image]

Given that it sounds like you just want some random values in between an upper and lower bound - are you sure you need to define a mean and standard deviation (or even know what those might be?) If you don't need to model that you'd be better off just using:

```
runif(4, min = 1494396000, max = 1494397800)
```